# Crop images using dimensions extracted from txt file

Tags: python, image, opencv

I would like to crop multiple images in my folder using PIL or opencv2. But, I have the dimensions in a text file having the same filename as the image. 
So, let's say my filename is 1_a.jpg, the dimensions (top left.x,width;top left.x,height) are in the 1_a.txt file.
So, my program must iterate through every file, select the dimensions and crop the image.
I am using a similar setup where I am trying to append  all the dimensions in a list separately and then trying to iterate images pointing to the lists while cropping but however, it doesn't work.
Kindly help.

Find my code below:-

```
for f in glob.glob(os.path.join(faces_folder_path, "*.txt")):
    file = open(f)
    small=[]
    data= file.read()

    print type(data)
    small.append(data.rstrip('\n'))
    print small
    print small[1]
    print type(small)
    x.append(small)
    print type(x)
    print x

    # print type(list)
    # print list
    # # print x
    # x.append(list)
    # for i,val in enumerate(x):
    #     print val[0]



for f in glob.glob(os.path.join(faces_folder_path, "*.png")):

    imgfile = f[53:75]
    print imgfile
    img=cv2.imread(imgfile)
    cv2.imshow('image',img)
    print (x[i])
    print type(x[i])
    # new_image=img[x[i]]
    # cv2.imshow('cropped',new_image)

    # cv2.imsave('imgfile',new_image)

    i+=1
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: I think you are assuming that the two glob calls will return *.txt and *.png files in the same order, but that is not necessarily true. There are two things that might help: (1) during the loop over *.txt, store the data in a dictionary with f[-4] (the filename minus '.txt') as the key, e.g., d[f[-4]]=small. Then during the loop over *.png, retrieve the data by accessing d[f[-4]]. (2) skip the loop over the *.txt files, and just read the .txt file while you are looping over the *.png files. You could do this with something like `f_text = open(f[-4]+'.txt')`

Comment: Thanks! That helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be best to just cycle through all of the PNG files, and for each one attempt to find a matching text file as follows:

```
import glob
import os
import re

faces_folder_path = r"c:\myfiles"

for png_file in glob.glob(os.path.join(faces_folder_path, "*.png")):
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(png_file))

    try:
        with open(os.path.join(faces_folder_path, '{}.txt'.format(name))) as f_text:
            re_crop = re.search(r'(\d+),(\d+);(\d+),(\d+)', f_text.read())

            if re_crop:
                x, width, y, height = [int(v) for v in re_crop.groups()]

                # Add crop code here
            else: 
                print '"{}" text file format not understood'.format(png_file)
    except IOError as e:
        print '"{}" has no matching txt file'.format(png_file)
```

This takes the file path to each png file and extracts the base filename. It then constructs a matching txt file, loads this in and uses a regular expression to try and find the required crop details. Each entry is converted to `int`.

This assumes an example text file would look something like this:

```
0,100;10,50
```